# how to make post call with custom object using volley in android

Tags: android, spring-boot, android-volley

am new to android can any one answer for this question please, i tried alot but didn't find correct stuff.i want to  send a my custom user object to  spring rest service

Employee Object:
in android and spring

```
  public class Employee{
        String firstname;
        String lastname;

//setters and getter goes here
        }
```

GsonRequest:

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
        public final Gson gson = new Gson();
        private final Class<T> clazz;
        private final Map<String, String> headers;
        private final Response.Listener<T> listener;
        private final Object dataIn;

        /**
         * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
         *
         * @param url     URL of the request to make
         * @param clazz   Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
         * @param headers Map of request headers
         */
        public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                           Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.headers = headers;
            this.listener = listener;
            this.dataIn = null;
        }

        public GsonRequest(String url, Object dataIn, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
                           Response.Listener<T> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
            super(Method.POST, url, errorListener);
            this.dataIn = dataIn;
            this.clazz = clazz;
            this.headers = headers;
            this.listener = listener;

        }

        @Override
        public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
            return gson.toJson(dataIn).getBytes();
        }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
        }

        @Override
        protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
            listener.onResponse(response);
        }

        @Override
        protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            try {
                String json = new String(
                        response.data,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
                return Response.success(
                        gson.fromJson(json, clazz),
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                return Response.error(new ParseError(e));

            }
        }
    }
```

Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {
    Button clickbtn;
    TextView resText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_layout);
clickbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        resText=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytext);


  clickbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {

          Employee emp=new Employee();
          emp.setFirstname("naresh");
          RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

          GsonRequest<Employee> myReq = new GsonRequest<Employee>("http://192.168.10.37:8088/adduser",
                  emp,
                  Employee.class,
                  new HashMap<String, String>(),
                  new Response.Listener<Employee>() {
                      @Override
                      public void onResponse(Employee response) {

                      }
                  },
                  new Response.ErrorListener() {
                      @Override
                      public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                          Log.i("post error","post error",error);
resText.setText(error.getMessage());
                          Log.d("post error","post error",error);
                      }
                  });


          queue.add(myReq);




      }
  });

    }
}
```

spring rest service:

```
@RequestMapping("adduser")
public void addUser(@Requestbody User user){
Sysetm.out.println(user.getFirstname());
}
```

Exception:

```
          at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
E/Volley: [216] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 415 for http://192.168.10.37:8088/adduser
I/post error: post error
              com.android.volley.ServerError
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
                  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
D/post error: post error
              com.android.volley.ServerError
                  at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:163)
                  at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:112)
```

Comment: Try adding `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` inside `getHeaders()`

Comment: thank you very much @BNK,it is working fine.can you add as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As my comment, please add `headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");` inside `getHeaders()`.